# finding the max and minimum of two columns in dataframe in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am creating a simple dataframe with country, GDP and Population. 
I want to find the country with max (GDP ) and min (population) from the dataframe.

Tried groupby , agg functions but unable to get the matching results. Can someone help with the Panda syntax for this.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([['India',90, 40000],['Nepal',100, 3000],['SL',800, 2000]]),columns=['country','gdp', 'pop'])

  country  gdp    pop
0   India   90  40000
1   Nepal  100   3000
2      SL  800   2000
```

Expecting output :

```
SL 800 2000
```

Comment: What if the result for the max and min functions is two different countries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([['India',90, 40000],['Nepal',100, 3000],['SL',800, 2000]]),columns=['country','gdp', 'pop'])

df1['gdp'] = df1['gdp'].astype('int')
df1['pop'] = df1['pop'].astype('int')

df1[(df1['gdp']==df1['gdp'].max()) & (df1['pop']==df1['pop'].min())]
```

Result:

```
  country  gdp   pop
2      SL  800  2000
```